# Importing my lib doesn't work right with devtool off

Tags: webpack

https://github.com/imarc/clockvine-vue/blob/master/webpack.config.js

This is mostly my library, and I'm trying to change my build script from `webpack --mode development` to `webpack --mode production` but if I do, my project using this lib throws warnings saying that the exports can't be found, like this:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 137 warnings5:01:48 PM

 warning  in ./resources/js/admin/operations/store.js

 "export 'ApiModule' was not found in 'clockvine-vue'
```

I've narrowed it down to that if I leave it as `webpack --mode development` and simply change the config from to `"devtool": false` - so disabling the eval sourcemaps that are by default in dev - that's enough to break my lib.

What else could changing `devtool` be doing to my project besides the sourcemaps? Why would sourcemaps affect the exports?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing the library with `import`/`require` you should not use libraryTarget as `var`, it is used when you intend to use the output library from a `script` tag

Use `libraryTarget: 'umd'`

webpack.config.js

```
..
..
  output: {
    filename: 'Clockvine.js',
    library: 'LIB',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: __dirname + '/lib',
  },
```

From the docs

> You can expose the library in the following ways:
>
> - Variable: as a global variable made available by a `script` tag    (`libraryTarget:'var'`).
> - This: available through the `this` object (`libraryTarget:'this'`).
> - Window: available through the `window` object, in the browser (`libraryTarget:'window'`).
> - UMD: available after AMD or CommonJS `require` (`libraryTarget:'umd'`).

Comment: I should have linked to a commit at the time of the question - [it was umd then](https://github.com/imarc/clockvine-vue/blob/e7c4a8c83a0ea891b7b8cb88c34f3adece152e84/webpack.config.js).

I think I found the answer - I don't think webpack 4 supports the ES Module syntax for exports at all - I did find this plugin which seems to have done what I wanted:

https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/webpack-how-to-generate-an-es-module-bundle/